# Deleting documents in mongodb where a field of document is not divisible exactly by some number?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with some documents like

```
[ 
  {
    name: "Test",
    dummyValue: 12
  },
  {
    name: "Test",
    dummyValue: 10
  }
]
```

Now I need to delete all collections whose dummyValue is not exactly divisible by 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out this,

```
db.collection.remove({'dummyValue':{$not:{$mod:[5,0]}}})
```

read more about ['$mod' here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/mod/)